# QGIS Training manual 21.14.1 : Where is Query Builder in QGIS 3.6?

Tags: qgis-3

I am new to GIS and QGIS and I am going through the training manual. It says to "Open theQuery Builder by right-clicking on the all_terrain layer in the Layers panel, and selecting the Properties→Sourcetab."

This does not exist as far as I can tell in 3.6. No other posted questions have an answer. Help?

@ahmadhanb stated that I should do what is written out above. The problem I am facing is that this is what I get when I do as ahmadhanb suggests: [image: screenshot]

I am using windows 10 if that helps any.

Comment: What is the format of your data? Is it raster or vector?

Comment: Raster file. I am following the training manual in section 21.14.1.

Comment: I updated my answer. There is no Query Builder for raster data. The Query builder is only available for vector data.

Comment: @Mark can you provide a link to that training manual?

Comment: [link](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/pdf/en/QGIS-testing-QGISTrainingManual-en.pdf#page=97&zoom=180,-57,843)

Comment: The `all_terrain` layer the manual refers to [here](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/pdf/en/QGIS-testing-QGISTrainingManual-en.pdf#section.21.14) is a vector layer. As @ahmadhanb mentioned in his answer you will find the query builder for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data is raster data, there is no `Query builder` for raster.

[image]

If the data is vector data, then right-click the layer in the table of contents `-> Properties -> Source tab -> Query Builder` at the lower right corner of the window:

[image]

Comment: I clarified my question by editing it. I am new to stack exchange so my apologies if this is not the right way to go about it.

Comment: @Mark If the answer solved your problem please accept it so that it will help others.